# How to cancel specific repeated UILocalNotification?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, uilocalnotification

I schedule UILocalNotification with repeatInterval = every day, but i wanna cancel specific notification, for example notification on the day after tomorrow. Can i do that?

Comment: Iterate through the scheduled notifications in `UIApplication.shard().scheduledLocalNotifications` and check the `fireDate` on each notification. If the `fireDate` matches the one you want to cancel, remove the notification.

Comment: @Wes In "scheduledNotifications" is only one notification. There is no future notifications, so i can't compare a firedate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i do that

No. If this was configured as a repeating daily notification, you cannot magically remove one repetition from it. You would have to cancel the *entire* notification and reschedule starting the day after the day after tomorrow.

Comment: Well, it isn't going to do this by magic, if that's what you mean. It is your code that needs to be flexible. For example if you had separate notifications for each day, then you could remove one.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:100];

     localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

now list out all notification that you have added.

```
-(void)localNotifcationList{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
    {
        UILocalNotification* yourEventSequence = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = yourEventSequence.userInfo;
        NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
        //Based on your userinfo cancel particular notification.
// You can also compare fire date here
}
```

I hope this code will work.